Android: What is the URIs for multi-sim phones?
I need to access contacts from SIM cards on multi-sim phones. What URIs should I use?
On phones with single SIM the URI "content://icc/adn" works.
The same URI works for accessing first SIM on multi-sim phones. How to access the second SIM and possibly third SIM?
